# BCC not reaching recipient

Tags: email, confirmation

For confirmation emails, does the CC have to be filled in for the BCC to work? I have instances where the BCC did not reach the recipients, but I had not entered a CC address, so I'm wondering if that is the cause. If not, what would be the cause?

Comment: You could use
define('CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG', 1); and define('CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG_AND_SEND', 1); (see here https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/#changing-file-based-settings) to log the outbound emails and see if they are not being sent or if they are being sent and aren't being delivered for some reason, which can happen.

Answer (score 1):

A BCC doesn't need a CC to work - I just tested it.  My first thought is that the problem might be that the receiving email server discarded it as spam. Where my clients use email I install Mailjet to make sure that emails get delivered. There are other email delivery engines as well, so you have a choice.

Comment: my recollection is that i saw issues wayback that BCC were actually not 'B' at all. Seems an entirely unhelpful comment by me, other than to flag i think there have been previous issues with BCC not working 'as intended'